# If $\sum a_n$ converges then $\sum (-1)^n \frac {a_n}{1+a_n^2}$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Could you please give me some hint how to deal with this question:

If $\sum a_n$ converges,
does this necessarily mean that $\sum (-1)^n \frac {a_n}{1+a_n^2}$ must converge also ?

Thanks.

Comment: The result holds at least when all $(a_n$ are positive. (check for absolute convergence)

Comment: what about $a_n=(-1)^n\frac{1}{n}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $a_n = (-1)^n\cdot \dfrac{1}{n}$, then the conclusion does not follow.

Answer (score 4):

In fact there's a theorem: if $f$ is a function on $\mathbb R$ such that $\sum_n f(a_n)$ converges whenever $\sum_n a_n$ converges, then $f$ is linear in a neighbourhood of $0$.  This was proved by G. Wildenberg, American Mathematical Monthly 95 (1988)
542-544.  Y. Benjamini's solution to Problem E3404, American Mathematical
Monthly 99 (1992) 466-467 contains an extension:

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a mapping of normed spaces such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(a_n)$ converges whenever $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges (both in the norm topology).
Then there is a neighbourhood of $0$ on which $f$ is equal to a bounded linear
operator.

I have a slight additional extension (unpublished):

Let $f: X -> Y$ be a mapping of Banach spaces such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(a_n)$ converges weakly whenever $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges (strongly).  Then
there is a neighbourhood of $0$ on which $f$ is equal to a bounded linear
operator.

Comment: It's a nice result, where can I found the American Mathematical Monthly 95 (1988) 542-544 please ? (Je suis un étudiant français.)

Comment: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2322761
Ask your university librarian if they have online access or if they have it on paper.