# If $\sum a_n$ is convergent , then $\sum {a_n}^2$ convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I found proofs telling that if $\sum a_n$ with $a_n>0$ is convergent (hence absolutely), then  $\sum {a_n}^2$ **always** convergent.

But what happens if we do not suppose that $a_n>0$?

My guess is that as $a_n \to 0$, $\exists n_0$ such that $\forall n \geq n_0, -\frac{1}{2} \leq a_n \leq \frac{1}{2} \implies 0 \leq a_{n}^2 \leq \frac{1}{2}a_n < a_n$ and conclude with comparison test. Is it right ?

Comment: How are you concluding $0\le a_n^2 <a_n$ when $a_n$ might be negative? Note that $x\le y$ does not imply $x^2\le y^2$ when $x$ and $y$ are not assumed to be non-negative: $-1 \le 0$ but $(-1)^2 > 0^2$.

Comment: A clumsy multiplication, my bad

Answer (score 8, accepted):

counterexample: $a_n=(-1)^n \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the only functions $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $\sum_n f(a_n)$ is convergent whenever $\sum_n a_n$ is convergent are those that are linear in a neighbourhood of $0$.  See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744674/if-sum-a-n-converges-then-sum-1n-frac-a-n1a-n2-converges/744782#744782)

Comment: What do you mean by linear in a neighborhood of 0 ?

Comment: I mean there are some constants $c$ and $\epsilon$ with $\epsilon > 0$, such that $f(x) = c x$ for $-\epsilon < x < \epsilon$.